# Merging two datasets conditional on 3 variables in SAS

Tags: merge, sas, conditional-statements

I am quite new to using SAS and would like to ask for your help on merging two datasets that do not contain one key identifier but require a combination of three conditions to be merged successfully.

I have two datasets:

- Dataset 1 contains information on client visits including `StartDate`, `EndDate`, `EmployeeNumber` and `CustomerNumber`.
- Dataset 2 contains information on certain activities that may have been performed during the visits in addition to the "Date" when the activity has been carried out and `EmployeeNumber` and `CustomerNumber`

The goal is to keep the first dataset and add information from the second dataset in case it is available - based on a match of date, employee number and customer number.

It is important that the date variable in the activity dataset is just on day while in the visits dataset it is a range between start and end date. So, the data sets look like this: 
[Base datasets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOLE6.jpg)

Logically, it should be a merge based on three conditions:

1. IF EmployeeNumber = EmployeeNumber
2. IF CustomerNumber = CustomerNumber
3. IF Date is between StartDate and EndDate
   Then: Update visits dataset with information from activity dataset

So, the ideal new dataset would look like this:
[Intended result of merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmdmI.jpg)
If there is no entry in the activity dataset, the new data set should simply contain a blank for the respective variables. For all matches, it should add the respective variable.

When trying (rather simple) merge statements in SAS, I usually get an error message stating that "BY variables are not properly sorted on data set". Furthermore, I am not sure how to implement the conditions (in particular the match of date to a range) properly.

Can this sort of merge be done in SAS or SQL?
Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to use proc sql for this kind of stuff, it's just a relatively simple join in which SQL excels. Try something like this:

```
proc sql;

create table merged_data as
  select a.*, b.other_variable, b.other_variable2
  from dataset1 as a
  left join dataset2 as b 
    on a.EmployeeNumber = b.EmployeeNumber 
    and a.CustomerNumber = b.CustomerNumber
    and b.Date between a.StartDate and a.EndDate
;

quit;
```

Comment: Great, thanks. It seems to work. One little adaption was necessary: it should be "a.EndDate" instead of b. Still trying to figure out why the merged data set contains more rows than the original dataset1. Any idea?

Comment: Right, that was a typo on my part, sorry about that. Fixed.

Comment: About the extra rows: there must be duplicates somewhere. Does your data have several Activities per Client Visit, for the same Employee and Customer?